# Get xml node child together with xml tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Parent>  
  <ParentElement1>PE1</ParentElement1>  
  <ParentElement2>PE2</ParentElement2>  
  <Child>  
    <ChildElement1>CE1</ChildElement1>  
    <ChildElement2>CE2</ChildElement2>  
  </Child>  
</Parent>
```

I need to extract Child present inside Parent,

Output must look like :

```
<Child>  
  <ChildElement1>CE1</ChildElement1>  
  <ChildElement2>CE2</ChildElement2>  
</Child>`
```

I have tried with XPath expression `/Parent/Child`,
 but it selects text only CE1 & CE2.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to use `<xsl:copy-of>` instead of `<xsl:value-of>`.

From the XSL spec: `The xsl:copy-of element can be used to copy a node-set over to the result tree without converting it to a string.`.

Use the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<!-- To get rid of <?xml ... declaration, use the following:
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" /> -->

<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- use copy-of instead of value-of -->
  <xsl:copy-of select="/Parent/Child" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Child>
   <ChildElement1>CE1</ChildElement1>
   <ChildElement2>CE2</ChildElement2>
</Child>
```